# What is the physiological difference between looking at small things vs far away things?

Tags: human-eye

If you look at an item that is far away, vs a smaller version of the same item up close, such that both objects take up the exact same degrees of arc in your field of view, what do your eyes do differently to focus on that item? I know that your brain may interpret the information differently, but do your eyes themselves actually do anything different?

Edit:
What I've looked at so far:
I have already learned about the basics of how the eye uses ciliary muscles to bend the lens to look at up close objects, and then relaxes in order to look at far away objects.

What I do not understand is how, or even *whether*, the eye behaves differently when dealing with size. For example, what is the difference between reducing the font size on your computer monitor vs simply moving your computer monitor further away? You can reduce the seconds of arc taken up by the text by either method, and decrease the angle of the light hitting your retina by the same amount.

I have read many articles and watched videos about how the eye works, but all of these materials have focused on distance of viewed objects from the observer, without regard to size. My question here has to do with how or whether changes in size of an observed object elicts a different physiological response than moving that object closer and further away.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: Please read about the lens of the human eye.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I've read a lot about the mechanisms by which the eye works including but not limited to the functioning of the lens and the muscles/tendons surrounding it. Now, I've only gone as deep as learning about ciliary muscles / zonular tension, but so far I've found nothing that moves in the direction of answering this question, which is why I'm here. What specifically regarding the lens are you referring to? Thanks. Again, I'm asking specifically about situations where the same percentage of your field of view is taken up by these different-sized versions of the same object.